# Useful git commit messages for merged branches

Tags: git, branching

*As a follow-up to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166486/git-commit-messages-with-nvie-branching-model/166489#comment320228_166489):*

If I'm working on a team by myself, I can maintain useful commit messages when merging branches by squashing all the commits to a single diff and then merging that diff. That way I can easily see what changes were introduced in the branch, and I have a single summary describing the feature/change/whatever that was accomplished in that branch when browsing the master branch.

My question now is, how can I accomplish this when working with a team? In that situation, the branches will  be pushed to a remote repository, meaning that [I can't squash all the commits in the branch down to a single commit](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html#The-Perils-of-Rebasing). If the branch is public, can I still have a single useful merge commit in the master branch? (By "useful" I mean that the commit in the master line tells me (1) a useful summary of what was done in the branch and (2) diffs of the same.)

Answer (score 10):

This turns out to be pretty simple to do, using some `git merge` flags I wasn't familiar with.

- The `-e` flag allows you to edit the message that occurs when you merge.
- The `--log` flag appends the one-line commit message from all commits in the branch to be merged to the commit message, making it easier to remember what you've done.